# Checking if a value is set within a PHP for loop using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Using Laravel, I want to loop through a series of grades (from '0' through '12') and, if a grade is found in my intermediate/pivot table, I want the class for that specific matching item to append 'active'.

(For example's sake, within my intermediate table, I have set it to have two active **grade_id**s: 6 and 7.)

I tried a for loop:

```
@for ($x=0; $x<=12; $x++)
    @if ($x === 0)
        <button class="circular small ui icon button">K</button>
    @else
        <button class="circular small ui icon button">{{ $x }}</button>
    @endif
@endfor
```

And this loops nicely through the grades from 0 (K) to 12 just fine. But then how do I make *active* the items that match in the DB? I need to somehow add a foreach to output the $grades as $grade (or similar) and check if $x = $grade.

But if I try an idea like that:

```
@for ($x=0; $x<=12; $x++)
    @if ($x === 0)
        <button class="circular small ui icon button">K</button>
    @else
        @foreach ($grades as $key=>$value)
            <button class="circular small ui icon button">{{ $value }}</button>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endfor
```

the logic mucks things up by outputting K, 6, 7 with the 6, 7 being repeated 12 times. Yup, that's what I have effectively told it to do.

And doing it this way obviously doesn't work because I am only going to get a result that equals the number of rows matching in my DB:

```
<?php $x = 0; ?>
@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    @if ($x === 0)
        <button class="circular small ui icon button">K</button>
    @else
        <button class="circular small ui icon button">{{ $x }}</button>
    @endif
    <?php $x++; ?>
@endforeach
```

So, how do I output each/all of the grades (from 0 - 12) while checking if each one matches the value (grade_id) set in the intermediate database? I am guessing that this is a pretty simple task but I cannot think of what the control structure might be called that I can Google or search SO for...

*[Note that I have not included the table structure as I don't think this is relevant to the question.]*

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a CSS class to the button? `<button class="circular small ui icon button active">` ?

Comment: Yes, but only if the value of the grade matches the value of a row in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@for ($x=0; $x<=12; $x++)
@if ($x === 0)
    <button class="circular small ui icon button">K</button>
@else
    <button class="circular small ui icon button {{ in_array($x, $grades)?' selected' : ''}}">{{ $x }}</button>
@endif
@endfor
```

modified for blade notation

Comment: I'm getting "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given"

Comment: cast it to an array in your controller using (array)$grades. If the object has a toArray method you can use $grades->toArray() inside the in_array

Comment: I set $grades = (array) $grades; in the Controller. Page loads fine, however, nothing is showing as 'active'.

Comment: That is because your object is not taking the cast lightly. Try building a new array in the controller and using the new array in the view

Comment: I am not using Eloquent. I am using Query Builder. I've echoed out the array and it is multidimensional, so in_array won't work...

Comment: Nothing in your code made it look like it was multidimensional. In any case your exception states that you have an object where you should have an array. Solution?!?! make it an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149829/discussion-between-sheldon-scott-and-claudio-pinto).

Comment: I modified my query to use Eloquent and then used the 'pluck' method to retrieve the values and then used your solution above. $grades = ResourceGrade::where('id', $id)->pluck('grade_id')->toArray();  That worked just right for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have the grades in a separate array and use php's `in_array` to check if this grade requires `active` or not, example:

```
@for ($x=0; $x<=12; $x++)
@if ($x === 0)
    <button class="circular small ui icon button">K</button>
@else
    @if in_array($x, $grades)   
        <button class="circular small ui icon button active">{{ $value }}</button>
    @else
    @endif
@endif
```

@endfor

Comment: This throws an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('